# C# Not updating modified dataset to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've been working on a small project and came to an issue with a SQL Server database. The SQL Server database works fine when connecting and reading from it. There are no issues when it comes to the variables, they all update fine.

However, the database itself does not update at all. I believe it is the `da.Update` that is going wrong, but I've never worked with SQL before so I can't find what is wrong with it.

What it should do:

- Read data from the SQL Server table
- Put it in a `DataTable`
- Take changes from a list and put them into the `DataTable`
- Add the changes to the database

What it does do:

- Reads the data from the SQL Server table
- Puts it in a `DataTable`
- Takes changes from a list and puts them into the `DataTable`
- Doesn't update the database, but does not fail the try and catch

Code:

```
public void PushToDatabase()
{
    // Get update from list
    PropertiesList[0] = Name;
    PropertiesList[1] = Token;
    PropertiesList[2] = ClientID;
    PropertiesList[3] = ClientInfo;
    PropertiesList[4] = Owner;
    PropertiesList[5] = OtherID;
    PropertiesList[6] = Prefix;
    PropertiesList[7] = ApiKey;

    // Connect to the database
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Token, ClientID, ClientInfo, Owner, OtherID, Prefix, GoogleApi FROM dt", connection))
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        connection.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Load then modify the data
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.Rows[0].BeginEdit();
        dt.Rows[0][1] = PropertiesList[0];
        dt.Rows[0][2] = PropertiesList[1];
        dt.Rows[0][3] = PropertiesList[2];
        dt.Rows[0][4] = PropertiesList[3];
        dt.Rows[0][5] = PropertiesList[4];
        dt.Rows[0][6] = PropertiesList[5];
        dt.Rows[0][7] = PropertiesList[6];
        dt.Rows[0][8] = PropertiesList[7];
        dt.Rows[0].EndEdit();

        // Put the data back
        try
        {
            da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
            da.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand(true);
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            da.Update(dt);

            MessageBox.Show("Properties Updated", "Update");  //this completes fine and displays the updated message
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cant Store data", "Error");
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Sorry about the messy code I've been adding things in to try to fix this but I have not had any success.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) before the Update, so you need to remove `dt.AcceptChanges();`

A longer answer is that the AcceptChanges will mark all the added and updated rows as now being unmodified, and it will permanently delete the rows you've asked to be deleted (from the datatable -- not the table in Sql Server).  Then when you call Update, it scans the databable looking for any rows that are in "Added", "Modified" or "Deleted" status, and finds there are none (because you just changed them all to "Unmodified" via AcceptChanges), so nothing is sent to the database.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I have removed `dt.AcceptChanges();`. However, I am still having the same issue with the table not updating.

Comment: What does `da.Update(dt)` return?

Comment: Okay, It returns 0

Comment: Then it thinks there is nothing to change.